# What's the name for a UI component of a partial list with a "more" button?

Tags: lists

I use this pattern a lot, but I don't know what it's called:

```
Section 1
List item 1
List item 2
List item 3
View more


Section 2
List item 1
List item 2
List item 3
View more


Section 3
List item 1
List item 2
List item 3
View more
```

Functionally, it's similar to a scrollable horizontal list, except I don't like horizontal lists because they interfere with navigation gestures on mobile. Also, I think tabs are more common than this pattern, but I don't want to require users to click a tab before seeing list items for "section 2" and "section 3". Are there good reasons why this pattern isn't more common?

Comment: Not sure if it's really that, but it may be in the direction of [progressive disclosure](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/progressive-disclosure/).

Comment: Regarding why it's not more common, I'd say it's because it's not really a common pattern that you would seem to need often. Rather seems like a very niche use case  where it'd have any advantage over more common patterns, you just happen to like it.

Comment: Off-topic: why not scrolling? Is it because there's requery behind "view more"?

Comment: @PabloH scrolling which part? If you mean just showing the whole lists instead of "view more", each list is potentially really long, so users will never get to sections 2 and 3.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but I would caution against using this pattern. It is not accessible. Screen readers and people who magnify their screens will not be able to discern what the "read more" is about. If using this pattern, specify what you're reading more about so screen reader users will have context. "Read more about dogs." "Read more about cats." Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to such component as **Trimmed List (Single Column)**.

Then, when multiple such lists are combined together on the page, the **Segmented List Page** pattern emerges.